# Savings Account program in java

Tags: java

I've been working on a savings account program that tells me **"undefined for the type string"** I tried declaring it as a string is there something I'm missing? The output should show like this

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NRqN.jpg)

error on this line of code  **[  SavingsAccount.showBalance(savings);  ]**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class RunSavingsAccount
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  SavingsAccount savings=new SavingsAccount();
  double newRate,amount;
  char choice;
  try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("Enter interest rate: ");
      newRate=input.nextDouble();
      SavingsAccount.setInterestRate(newRate);
      System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
      amount=input.nextDouble();
      savings.deposit(amount);
      SavingsAccount.showBalance(savings);
      System.out.println("Press D for another deposit or W to withdraw: ");
      choice=input.next().charAt(0);
      if(choice=='d' || choice=='D')
      {
       System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
       amount=input.nextDouble();
       savings.deposit(amount);
       if(amount>=1000)
       {
        savings.addInterest();
       }
       System.out.println("Your new balance is "+savings.getBalance());
      }
    
      if(choice=='w' || choice=='W')
      {
       System.out.println("Enter withdraw amount: ");
       amount=input.nextDouble();
       savings.withdraw(amount);
       System.out.println("Your new balance is "+savings.getBalance());
      }
}

 }
```

Comment: Why are you passing `savings` into `showBalance`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you update your question to include the full error message you're getting, including the full stack trace that goes with it?  It isn't clear to me what the error message you give is saying.  Providing the actual output, including the stack trace, could give us a more precise view of what's going on. And a minor issue...please don't post images when it's possible to provide the equivalent text directly in your question.  You must have that information in text form.  So copy/paste it into your question rather than taking am image of it.

Comment: ...It would also be helpful for you to provide the code for the implementation of the SavingsAccount class.

Comment: @shmosel - Apparently, `showBalance` is a static method on the SavingsAccount class.  It therefore is not transparently associated with any particular instance of the SavingsAccount class, and therefore needs to be given the particular savings account instance that it should show the balance for.  Only a guess, of course, since we haven't been shown the code for that class.

Comment: @CryptoFool More likely it's expecting a String, judging by the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need another class named "SavingsAccount", since you're declaring a SavingsAccount in your code. That's what's missing you can't make it run without declaring another class that contains code in order for the program to run.

try this if it works.

```
class SavingsAccount
{
 private double balance;
 public static double interestRate=0;
 public
 SavingsAccount()
 {
  this.balance=0;
 }
 static void setInterestRate(double newRate)
 {
  interestRate=newRate;
 }
 static double getInterestRate()
 {
  return interestRate;
 }
 double getBalance()
 {
  return this.balance;
 }
 void deposit(double amount)
 {
  this.balance=this.balance+amount;
 }
 double withdraw(double amount)
 {
  if(this.balance>=amount)
  {
   this.balance=this.balance-amount;
  }
  else
  {
   amount=0;
  }
  return this.balance;
 }
 void addInterest()
 {
  double interest=this.balance*interestRate;
  this.balance=this.balance+interest;
 }
 static void showBalance(SavingsAccount account)
 {
  System.out.println("Your balance is "+account.getBalance());
 }
}
```

Comment: it works thank you I just need to edit out a little errors which the compiler told and run the program which is connected to the other one great help! :)